# How to rewrite NodeJS CryptoJS functions so they work in ReactJS web?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cryptojs

I have some code that was created for me by a past contractor that provided a working implementation of CryptoJS between a Unity3D client and NodeJS server app (as in encryption of client-server messages).

I am working on an implementation that needs to call the same server endpoints from a React web app. Basically, I need to be able to ensure that the React app provides the same results when encrypting and decrypting messages as the server (and hence the Unity3D implementation) does.

The existing encrypt/decrypt functions in the NodeJS app are shown below. They are somewhat more advanced than the standard CryptoJS examples and when I attempt to use them as-is in React, I get this error:

`TypeError: cryptoJS.createHash is not a function. (In 'cryptoJS.createHash('md5')', 'cryptoJS.createHash' is undefined)`

After some researching, I understand that potentially the 'use as-is' approach will fail because it's using a server side library on the client side, but I have been able to find anything that would explain how I would recreate the same code to work client-side.

```
encrypt(text, key, iv) {
    const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(cryptoJS.createHash('md5').update(key).digest('hex'), "hex")
    const ivBuffer = Buffer.from(cryptoJS.createHash('md5').update(iv).digest('hex'), "hex")
    const textBuffer = Buffer.from(text, 'utf8')
    let cipher = cryptoJS.createCipheriv(algorithm, keyBuffer, ivBuffer)
    let encryptedText = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(textBuffer), cipher.final()])
    return encryptedText.toString("base64")
}

decrypt(text, key, iv) {
    const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(cryptoJS.createHash('md5').update(key).digest('hex'), "hex")
    const ivBuffer = Buffer.from(cryptoJS.createHash('md5').update(iv).digest('hex'), "hex")
    let decipher = cryptoJS.createDecipheriv(algorithm, keyBuffer, ivBuffer)
    const textBuffer = Buffer.from(text, 'base64')
    var decipheredContent = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(textBuffer), decipher.final()])
    return decipheredContent.toString("utf8")
}
```

So, I need to figure out how to replace these encrypt/decrypt functions with ones that compile and function in client side in React web. Any help in steering me in the right direction or assisting with the code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic at all but seems that crypto-js is eq library https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js (https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/28#issuecomment-103167404)

Comment: Is this about the `npm crypto-js` package? Have you tried following the client-side installation instructions on the npm page? Have you tried `cryptoJS.md5.createHash()`?

Comment: Thank you @MoshFeu for the link you provided.

So, this works to create a hashed value:

`const keyHash = cryptoJS.MD5(serverKey).toString()`

And this works to create a buffer:

`const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(cryptoJS.MD5(serverKey).toString(cryptoJS.enc.Utf16)).toString('hex')`

But as you can probably see, I'm really just guessing at the encoding, whatever I try doesn't derive the same value as the NodeJS server gets from the original code.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you for the response and help also. Yes, it is regarding `npm crypto-js`. I don't seem to be able to successfully use the library at all in React using the client side instructions on the npm page. I have also seen references to `npm i crypto-js` being the right approach in React. In the npm library, `md5` (lowercase) doesn't exist, while `MD5` is a function in of itself, so there is no `cryptoJS.md5.createHash()`.

Comment: Still stuck on this if anyone can help! :)